# How to connect to a Postgres server in a Docker (1.12.0) container on a Mac?

Tags: macos, postgresql, docker

The latest release of Docker doesn't use a virtual machine anymore, instead using a hypervisor to connect to the containers. This means I can no longer login to postgres with `psql`:

```
➜  postgres git:(master) ✗ docker run -d -p 5433:5432 db postgres
<sha>
➜  postgres git:(master) ✗ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
111f3bed4c52        db                  "/docker-entrypoint.s"   17 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:5433->5432/tcp   zen_hugle
➜  postgres git:(master) ✗ psql -p 5433 -U postgres
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5433"?
```

I have also tried specifying localhost as the host, but that results in a strange output:

```
➜  postgres git:(master) ✗ psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres
psql: %
```

Does anyone know what to do in this case? Thank you.

Comment: FYI, it does use a VM, just not VirtualBox, it uses xhyve Virtual Machine on Mac but does use Unix sockets for networking. If you need the "native" model (e.g., to closer mimic a production system), you may be better off using a traditional VM environment.

Comment: I assume in your run statement it should be `docker run -d -p 5433:5432 --name=db postgres`

Answer (score 1):

With follwing command,

```
docker run -d -p 5433:5432 db postgres
```

You are exporting your docker's 5432 port to docker-engine's 5433 port. Not your host machine's 5433.

Fetch your docker-machine's IP address with following command (assuming your docker vm name is `default`)

```
docker-machine env default
```

This should give you result similar to following lines

```
> export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
> export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
> export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/<your-user>/.docker/machine/machines/default"
> export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
```

Use your docker-machine's IP address to connect to Postgres running in container

```
>psql -h 192.168.99.100 -p 5433 -U postgres

psql (9.5.0, server 9.5.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me. Thanks! I was using the wrong IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect over tcp by using an IP like `psql -h 0.0.0.0 -p 5433 -U postgres` (or 127.0.0.1, etc.).

Using the default or "localhost" will try using the local domain socket (although the version of Docker doesn't change this behavior, you will generally need to connect to a containerized db via tcp).